# Delete Object in Active Directory by IADS

Tags: c++, active-directory, ldap

this is a sample code in MSDN for deleting an object such as user , ...
but when i am using  this example
this line "pOps->DeleteObject(0);" result is "E_ACCESSDENIED"  why ?
would you please help me

```
IADsContainer *pCont;
LPWSTR adsPath = L"LDAP://OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com";
HRESULT hr = ADsGetObject(adsPath,IID_IADsContainer,(void**)&pCont);
if (FAILED(hr)) exit(hr);

IADsDeleteOps *pOps;
hr = pCont->QueryInterface(IID_IADsDeleteOps,(void**)&pOps);
pCont->Release();
if(FAILED(hr) exit(hr);
pOps->DeleteObject(0);
pOps-Release();
```

Answer (score 0):

The account you are using to perform the action does not have permission to delete the target object.

Comment: i have administrator  user name and password !

Comment: Is it a Container object?  You might have to delete the contents first before deleting the container.

Comment: did u test it by your  self ?  i test it on empty Organization Unit and didn't work ! :( if u test it  please tell me details

Answer (score 0):

Use the ADsOpenObject which takes username and password as arguments pass the administrator credentials and the code will work fine.
For reference [Link](https://microsoft.public.adsi.general.narkive.com/OUku7EXm/explain-getobject-vs-openobject)